# Java; Runtime Interpretation; Strategies To Add Plugins

Tags: java, interpreter, extensible

I'm beginning to start on my first large project.  It will be a program very similar to [Rosetta Stone](http://www.rosettastone.com/offer/ggbts09?s_kwcid=rosetta%20stone|3270086025&gclid=CKn33qH9v5wCFSQeDQodTW7hoQ).  It will be a program, used for learning a foreign language, written in Java using Swing.  In my program I plan on the user being able to select downloaded courses to learn from.  I will be able to create an English course since I am a native English speaker.  However, I want people who speak other languages to be able to write courses for users to use as well (this is an essential part for my program to work).

Since I want the users to be able to download courses of languages they want, having it hard-coded into the program is out of the question.  The courses needed to be interpreted during the runtime.  Also since I want others to collaborate with my work (ie make courses), I need to make it easy for them to do so.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

The idea I have come up with is having a strict empty course outline (hard-coded) with a simple xml file which details the text and sounds to be used.  The drawback to this is that it extremely limits the author.  Different languages may need to start out with learning different parts.

Any advice on the problem at hand as well as the project as a whole will be greatly appreciated.  Any links to any relevant resources or information would also be greatly appreciated.

Think you for your time and effort,

Joseph Pond

Comment: +1 Interesting topic. Could you try to make more visible what the question/questions is/are? .. .Is it about strategies to .. add ... plugins?.. Could you emphasize a bit the programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are set on doing this from scratch (Will's idea isn't bad), What I would do is first lay down the file format that would be easiest to create your language course in.  It could be XML, plaintext or some other format you come up with yourself.

You will probably need some flexibility in the language format because you will want to actually be able to specify things like questions and answers.  XML is a pain because of all the extra terminators, but it gives a good amount of meta-data.  If you like XML for that, you may consider defining your language file in YML, it gives you the data of XML but uses whitespace delineators instead of angle brackets.

You probably also want to define your file in the language it's created for, so you might or might not want to require english words as keys.  If you don't want any english, you may have to skip both XML and YML and come up with your own file format--possibly where the layout and/or special symbols define the flow and "functionality".

Once you have defined the file format, you won't have to worry about hard-coding anything... you won't be able to because it will already be in the file.

Plug-in functionality would be nice as well... This is where your definition file also contains information that tells you what class to instantiate (reflectively) and use to parse/display the data.  In that way you could add new types of questions just by delivering a new jar file.

If this is confusing, sorry, this is difficult in a one-way forum because I can't look at your face and see if you're following me or if I'm even going in the right direction.  If you think I'm on the right track and want more details (I've done a bit of this stuff before) feel free to leave a follow-up question (or an email address) in a comment and I'd be glad to discuss it with you further.

Comment: I would like to try and make my own file format in doing this, as I do intend this to be more so a learning experience.  I would be very grateful if you would be willing to go a little further in depth.
My email is Joseph dot M dot Pond  (gmail)

Answer (score 5):

Simply, you should base your program on a system such as Eclipse RCP, or the Netbeans Platform. Both of these systems already deal with exactly this problem, and both are perfectly adequate for this task. They're not just for IDEs.

It's a larger first step as you will need to learn one of these platforms beyond simply just Swing.

But, they solve the problem, and their overall organization and technique will serve your program well anyway.

Don't reinvent this wheel, just learn one of these instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I was doing this, I'd seriously consider using Eclipse EMF to model the "language" for defining courses.  EMF is rather daunting to start with, but it gives you:

- A high-level model that can be entered/edited in a variety of ways.
- An automatic mechanism for serializing "instances" (i.e. courses) to XML.  (And you can tinker with the serialization if you choose.)
- Automatically generated Java classes for in-memory representations of your instances.  These provide APIs that are tuned to your model, an generic ones that are the EMF equivalent of Java reflection ... but based on EMF model classes rather than Java classes.
- An automatically generated tree editor for your "instances".
- Hooks for implementing your own constraints / validation rules to say what is a valid "course".

Related Eclipse plugins offer:

- Mappings to text-based languages with generation of parsers/unparsers
- Mappings to graphical languages; e.g. notations using boxes / arrows / etc
- Various more advanced persistence mechanisms
- Comparisons/differencing, model-to-model transformations, constraints in OCL, etc

I've used EMF in a couple of largish projects, and the main point that keeps me coming back for more is ease of model evolution ... compared with building everything at a lower level of abstraction.  If my model (language) needs to be extended / changed, I can make the necessary changes using the EMF Model editor, regenerate the code, extend my custom code to do the right stuff with the extensions, and I'm pretty much done (modulo conversion of stored instances).